# Regular expression comments multiline

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, regex

I would like to use Regular Expression for comments in multiline in C#. I have `@"/[*][\w\d\s]+[*]/"` but with that expression only comments the text that appears between /* */ in singleline not in multiline.

Singleline:

```
       /* xxxxxxxx */
```

Multiline:

```
       /*
       xxxxxxx
       */
```

I don't know if I could explain well, but any questions or if you can refer to somewhere that provides this information I would appreciate it.

EDIT
In my example I have in one class

.
.
.

```
    public IList<ClassificationSpan> GetClassificationSpans(SnapshotSpan span)
    {
        List<ClassificationSpan> classifications = new List<ClassificationSpan>();
        string current = span.GetText();
        bool commentFound = false;
        foreach(var item in _colorTextoLanguage.Comments)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex(item, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var matches = reg.Matches(current);
            for(int i=0;i<matches.Count;i++)
            {
                commentFound = true;
                Match m =matches[i];
                Span new_span = new Span(span.Start.Position + m.Index, current.Length - m.Index);
                SnapshotSpan new_snapshot = new SnapshotSpan(span.Snapshot, new_span);
                var newText = new_snapshot.GetText();
                classifications.Add(new ClassificationSpan(new_snapshot, _commentType));
            }
        }
        if(commentFound)
            return classifications;
        Classify(classifications, current, span, _colorTextoLanguage.Custom, _classificationType);
        Classify(classifications, current, span, _colorTextoLanguage.Quoted, _stringType);
        Classify(classifications, current, span, _colorTextoLanguage.Keywords, _keywordType);
        Classify(classifications, current, span, _colorTextoLanguage.IdentifierTypes, _identifierType);
        Classify(classifications, current, span, _colorTextoLanguage.Numeric, _numericType);
        return classifications;
    }
```

.
.
.

and other class with

```
class ColorTextoLanguage
{
    #region Member Variables

    private List<string> _comments = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _quoted = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _numeric = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _keywords = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _identiferTypes = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _custom = new List<string>();


    #region Properties

    public List<string> Comments
    {
        get{return _comments;}
    }

    public List<string> Quoted
    {
        get{return _quoted;}
    }

    public List<string> Numeric
    {
        get{return _numeric;}
    }

    public List<string> Keywords
    {
        get{return _keywords;}
    }

    public List<string> IdentifierTypes
    {
        get{return _identifierTypes;}
    }

    public List<string> Custom
    {
        get{return _custom;}
    }

    #endregion

    #region ctor

    public ColorTextoLanguage()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods
    private void Initialize()
    {
        _comments.Add("//");
        _comments.Add(@"/\*(?:(?!\*/)(?:.|[\r\n]+))*\*/");

        _quoted.Add(@"([""'])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1");

        _numeric.Add(@"\b\d+\b")

        _keywords.Add(@"\bif\b");
        _keywords.Add(@"\belse\b");
        _keywords.Add(@"\bforeach\b");
        _keywords.Add(@"\bswitch\b");
        _keywords.Add(@"\bcase\b");
        .
        .
        .


        _identifierTypes.Add(@"\bint\b");
        _identifierTypes.Add(@"\bdate\b");
        _identifierTypes.Add(@"\bstring\b");
        .
        .
        .

    }
    #endregion
    #endregion
};
```

Not sure if this helps, but from what I see is quite similar to your example.
Thanks in addvance

Comment: So, you want to use a regular expression to *identify* a multi line comment?

Comment: How exactly are you using the regex? `Regex.Match("       /*\n       xxxxxxx\n       */", @"/[*][\w\d\s]+[*]/")` works for me. The regex has other problems, but multiline comments don't seem to be one of them.

Comment: Yes MichaelT. 

And what I have is reg.Matches(current)
current is an string with content the regular expression

Comment: Wait, what?  I don't see a single comment in your new examples.  Are you trying to use Visual Studio's Find utility and a Regex to Find C# Comments within your source files?  Or are you actually running a C# Project, which loads some text, and your modules search the Text for C# Comments?

Comment: Hi Suamere, this is a part of the example that I found on the internet. The example works fine for the words reserved, numbers, comments // and string "". 
What I try to do is apply syntax highlighting in my code, the example runs in the experimental instance of visual studio.
In the experimental instance I create a project and a class with my extension, in this class is that I want to detect multiple lines comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the regex:

```
/\*(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/
```

With RegexOptions.Singleline

```
new Regex(@"/\*(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hQ3vZ8)

`(?:(?!\*/).)*` will match any character except `*/`

EDIT: Version which should work in both modes:

```
/\*(?:(?!\*/)(?:.|[\r\n]+))*\*/
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for your answer. I use the regular expression but only works in sinleline, in multiline still don't works. However in the link regex101 works in singleline and multiline.

I have many regular expressions that work correctly on page regex101(Singleline and multiline), but in my example only works in singleline

Comment: @faduar I added a regex which should work for both single and multiline. Note: in regex101, single line is with mode `s`. For multiline, you remove `s` and use `m`.

Comment: Again, thanks for your answer, and sorry if I make a lots of questions but really i don't understand a lot. Could you give me an example of how it would be the regular expression?

Thanks very much and sorry for my english
Fabiana

Comment: Sorry, recently saw you edited the comment with the regular expression would work. But still does not work in my example.

Comment: @faduar I don't understand why it won't work. See this [ideone](http://ideone.com/wQZLvQ).

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thanks a lot for all your answers, but still not work. I try to follow your example in ideone but don't understand how work.
Thank you very much.
Fabiana.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\*([^*]*\*)*?/
```

`/\*` Match a Forward Slash followed by an Asterisk

`([^*]*\*)*?` (Match everything that is NOT a literal asterisk zero to infinite times, then match a literal asterisk), do this lazily zero or infinite times

`/` Match a Forward Slash.  If this fails, backtrack to the previous step and attempt one more lazy iteration.

Not only is this shorter and more clear, it also takes less Regex Steps to perform.  It is the most efficient way.

Note: There is no need to worry about collections.  But if you really care, you could make your group a non-capture group with `?:`

```
    /\*(?:[^*]*\*)*?/
```

Comment: Hi Suamere, thanks for you answer. The regular expression ([^*]*\*)*? match everything but the others only works in singleline.

Comment: Well, that expression in your comment is missing a backslash. And my answer is not dependent on singleline since there are no `Dots`, and not dependent on Multiline since there are no `^ or $`.  Are you creating a text-field where a user will input Code, and your app will alter the styles of things (such as comments) just like Vistual Studio does?

Comment: ... If so, you have a lot more to think about that Regex.  What if a person has code like so: `SharedClass.SharedMethod("/*blah") /* comment */`, it would break no matter what your regex is, because regex doesn't know where your actually programming stops.  That's why Visual Studio was done by people paid a lot of money.  They know what they're doing, and they don't use Regex to pick out their comments.

Answer (score 0):

To match a multi line comment you need a simple regex like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/\*.*?\*/", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Hope this helps you in your quest.

Comment: Hi Casperah, thank you very much for your answer but with this line still works only in single line not in multiline.

Comment: It works for me, the RegexOptions.Singleline is essential to make it work for multi line comments.

Answer (score 0):

The issue it not the regex at all. The reason this is not working is the fact that only a single line of code is being passed into the GetClassificationSpans() function at any one time. I'm having the same issue as you and from the look of the code you have provided, we followed the same tutorial.

This is not really an answer, it'll just help you identify what the actual issue is.

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment on the question, since it's "not an answer at all"

Comment: Yes it would but the site wouldn't let me due to having no reputation which is a result of having just created this account. I wanted to help anyone who is looking for this and it was the only way I could post.

Comment: Actually, I think this *is* the answer.  If the comment ends on a different line than it started on, the regex will never see the whole comment at once.  You have to detect the opening delimiter (`/*`), set a flag indicating the new state (multiline comment), and start looking for the closing delimiter (`*/`).  That's how most syntax coloring frameworks work in my experience, and a quick look at the VS SDK docs tells me this one is no exception.