# Regexp for /* */ comments

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out regexp to automatically remove all /* ... */ multiline comments in IDEA editor.

I've come to

```
/\*.*\n.*\n\*/
```

for two-lines comments but can't get how to make it for any number of lines.

Any suggestions?

**Note:** there is no support for 'dotall' mode in the IDEA replace tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe try this?

```
/\*[\s\S]*?\*/
```

`[\s\S]*?` is the usual substitute for `.*?` with the dotall flag.

Comment: I've already found a solution but got your solution on my tricks list.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i've got to use 3rd party regexp tool, because one in IDEA search&replace was kinda bugged.

This tool is "RegExp Plugin" for IDEA.

I've used it in dotall mode with such regexp:

```
/\*(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/
```

It works properly with multiple comment blocks.

Comment: @Jerry solution is better fitting to the question, so this solution is more like workaround. Leaving it here just in case someone find it useful.

Comment: That would be my first choice, but since I didn't know whether the regex supported negative lookaheads, I opted for the simpler solution. See, I used that very regex in another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18865739/1578604) =P

Answer (score 0):

```
/\*(.*\n)*\*/
```

Here `(.*\n)` means a line and then `(.*\n)*` means the repeating of the lines.

Comment: It is valid and i've tested it in another regexp editor without multiline mode. But somehow it's not working in IDEA's tool. Guess it's bugged and i've to use another tool.

Comment: You can try replacing the `\n` with `[\n\r]+` but not sure whether it will work or not!

Comment: This doesn't work. It requires the `*/` to come immediately after a newline.